# How to validate a field only when focus is out for this input element? (Unobtrusive validation)

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

How to validate a field only when focus is out for this input element?
Now, when I type into the input, validator  immediatelly validate my data. I want that validator  validate my data when I start to filling another one input.

Comment: You are using jQuery validate plug-in I'm assuming?

Comment: unobtrusive validation jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. The idea is to return false form OnKeyUp event: http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/validate-onkeyup-for-single-field-td121993.html

[ASP.net MVC 3 jQuery Validation; Disable Unobtrusive OnKeyUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022695/asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-validation-disable-unobtrusive-onkeyup)