# How to disable jquery validation on keyup and focusout for 1 specific html element when using the unobtrusive validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-events, unobtrusive-validation

By default, the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) is attaching validation handlers for `focusin`, `focusout` and `keyup` events.

1 of our validations is making a (synchronous) request to retrieve some data. I want to have that validation triggered only when the form is being submitted and not while the user is typing.

I know this can be [modified for the whole form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953104/68808), but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to dynamically disable `keyup` validation for 1 element?

**Update 1**:
I forgot to mention that I'm using [unobtrusive validation](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/). So I don't think the answer of @Mario Johnathan is not an option.

**Update 2**:
I tried the following things (`$element` is the element on which I want to change the validation behavior):

1. `$element.validate({focusout: false, keyup: false});`
2. `$element.keyup(function() { return false; });`
3. `$element.off('keyup');`
4. `$element.unbind('keyup');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I myself was in the same scenario. Below is the code which I used for it.

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
      onkeyup: function () {
        var originalKeyUp = $.validator.defaults.onkeyup;
        var customKeyUp =  function (element, event) {
          if ($("#your_element")[0] === element) {
            return false;
          }
          else {
            return originalKeyUp.call(this, element, event);
          }
        }

        return customKeyUp;
      }()
  });
```

Here what I have done is handle keyup events for that element so that validator doesn't do anything. For rest all elements the validator will kick into action. But the catch here is that particular element will have  no validation on keyup at all.

Comment: Thank you. It seems this could indeed be a correct approach. I can finally continue to work.

Comment: Do let me know if it works for you. Although I've submitted the answer after very long time, I'll be glad if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try overriding the onkeyup function and create an onkeyup variable that you can customize for each field

```
$(#signupForm).validate({
    onkeyup: function(element) {
        var element_id = $(element).attr('id');
        if (this.settings.rules[element_id].onkeyup !== false) {
            $.validator.defaults.onkeyup.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },
    rules: {
        myfield: {
            required: true,
            onkeyup: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is an option for me since I'm using unobtrusive validation, where the initialization is done in the unobtrusive validation plugin.
Can you think of any other option?

Answer (score 3):

Add a new event listener to the $element and prevent the event bubbling up the DOM tree using stopPropagation(), which will prevent any parent handlers (including validate) being notified.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
    $element.on('keyup',function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the validate options.

```
var validator = $('#form_id').validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    rules: {...},
    messages: {...}
});
```

Comment: sry, but that is changing things for the whole form, not just for 1 element, right?

Comment: yes is for the whole form, now is not going to check when the user leaves the input. Only when he submits the form

Comment: And my question was "Is there a way to dynamically disable keyup validation for 1 element?".. So NOT for the whole form :)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Until now I was able to achieve what I need by [changing the source code of the `jQuery.validation` plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/998).

By passing in the event (if any) to the validation methods, I'm able to check if it was triggered from a focusout or a keyup.

Not ideal, but working.

```
function validateWithSomeLongTakingCallback(source, args, event) {
    var shouldTriggerValidation = (!event || (event.type !== 'focusout' && event.type !== 'keyup'));

    if (!shouldTriggerValidation) {
        args.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From other forum:

> This is still an issue (jQuery 1.7.2 and Validation 1.9.0). I've
>   created a simple fix and will also submit a pull request.
>
> To fix: In jquery.validate.js in the "element" function (line 361) add
>   this if statement to the top of the function like so (leave everything
>   else the same):

```
element: function( element ) {
            //if the element is set to be ignored, don't continue validation
            if ( $(element).not(this.settings.ignore).length === 0 ) {
                return;
                }
            element = this.validationTargetFor( this.clean( element ) );
            this.lastElement = element;
            this.prepareElement( element );
            this.currentElements = $(element);
            var result = this.check( element ) !== false;
            if (result) {
                delete this.invalid[element.name];
            } else {
                this.invalid[element.name] = true;
            }
            if ( !this.numberOfInvalids() ) {
                // Hide error containers on last error
                this.toHide = this.toHide.add( this.containers );
            }
            this.showErrors();
            return result;
        },
```