# Avoid performing client side validation when typing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I noticed that validation occurs even when i am typing.
What i would like is that it only performs validation when another field is selected or when clicked on the submit button.

Is there a way to prevent validation when typing?

Comment: Which control is performing the validation? Client-side validation is exclusively performed using javascript, so you should inspect the js you are sending to the browser to find the culprit and disable it.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR ASP.MVC automatically performs client side validation when you enable validation and included the necessary scripts. No manual activation is required.

Comment: @jamie, you need to turn it off in web.config

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14316783/1385075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable as-you-type validation for all fields, try doing this:

```
$(function(){
    $.validator.setDefaults({
       onkeyup: false    // disable onkeyup events
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I do have to note that i had to put this code in front of my validate and validate unobtrusive scripts.

Comment: Yeah, you need to run this before unobtrusive validation kicks in! :)