# MVC Dataannotations - Only validate on Form Submit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, data-annotations

I need to validate the form only when I click the submit button and present the Error Messages based on the DataAnnotation's properties.

ViewModel:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field Required")]
 [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Message is to short")]
 public string Message { get; set; }
```

HTML:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
```

What happens is that when I submit the form with an empty Message, I get the "Field Required" message, but when I start writing in the field, the error message change to "Message is to short" but I only want this when I press the submit button again.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022695/asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-validation-disable-unobtrusive-onkeyup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Disable keyup validation on key up
var validator = $("#yourFormId").data("validator");
if (validator)
    validator.settings.onkeyup = false;
```

Comment: Hi thanks! It works great! just one more question, do you think it's possible to clear the error message from the field just when, after showing the error on submit, I click in the field the first time?

Comment: Not sure how to clear specific field's errors, but you should work on it in the `focus` (or `click`) event.